# Editing Chart.js legend template

Tags: chart.js

I am working on a project using chart.js. I want to display data in a Radar chart form. We have 5 different data sources. To make our radar chart more readable we have divided some of these data sources (some having much higher values than others), and our chart is looking good.

However the only problem now is that in our legend the data is displayed with a decimal place (as we have divided it).

Does anyone know how to edit the legend template in chart.js so that we can multiply the results shown for some of our data sets (so users do not see decimal point data)?

This the function in our app.js file that is creating the dataset for chart.js (notice some values divided):

```
  return largestStations.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
previousValue.datasets[index] = {
  label: currentValue.commonName.replace(' Underground Station', ''),
  // add chart formatting (needs to be made dynamic)
  fillColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)",
  strokeColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)",
  pointColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)",
  pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
  pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
  pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
  // end of chart formatting
  data: [
    app.getValueFromStation(currentValue, 'Gates') / 10,
    app.getValueFromStation(currentValue, 'Lifts'),
    app.getValueFromStation(currentValue, 'Payphones'),
    app.getValueFromStation(currentValue, 'Escalators') / 3,
    app.getValueFromStation(currentValue, 'Cash Machines')
  ]
};
return previousValue; }
```

We are currently using the default legend template in chart.js which looks like this:

```
<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>
```

Is editing the legend template the best solution for this problem? If anyone knows a better way to display this data (which has a big difference in range) using chart.js that would be very much welcomed also.

Comment: Are you asking about chart.js version 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your current legend?  I have only see legends contain the name of the dataset and not contain any detail regarding the data itself.  Just to be sure are you talking about Legends or Tooltips?

Answer (score -1):

this is from github:

You could add a personalized callback to the tooltip labels, where you round the values
e.g.

1 - tooltipItem.yLabel.toFixed(2) would return a value with 2 decimal places.

```
2.123.toFixed(2)
>> "2.12"
2.0001.toFixed(2)
>> "2.00"
```

2- Math.round(tooltipItem.yLabel * 100) / 100 would return a value rounded to the nearest 2nd decimal place.

```
Math.round(2.123 * 100) / 100
>> 2.12
Math.round(2.00001 * 100) / 100
>> 2

tooltips: {
callbacks: {
    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';

        if (label) {
            label += ': ';
        }
        label += tooltipItem.yLabel.toFixed(2);
        return label;
    }
}
```

}